# Writing html unicode symbols in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How do you write html code in javascript?

I want to write:

```
document.title = "Title " + (&#9652;);
```

where the html code is in parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it with the parentheses; that's invalid syntax. Just put it in your string and use the JavaScript Unicode syntax `\udddd`:

```
document.title = "Title \u9652";
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3x07vdy/2/) (note that jsFiddle won't let me change the title, so I change a div's contents instead).

Comment: It seems to be treating it like a string. I get the string code instead of the actual symbol. Is there a common reason for this?

Comment: @shell See my edit. I should have pointed out that you should use the `\udddd` syntax, instead of the HTML entity (`&#dddd`) syntax.

Comment: @shell Cool; glad to help!